# Изменить величину textSize в TextViewer для разных разметок

Tags: java, android

Для функционирования на разномасштабных устройствах под ОС Андроид,
Имеется две разметки `layout-sw200dp` и `layout-sw600dp`,
в Activity работает `textview_timeVydox.setTextSize(VYDOX_OUTPUT_FONT)`;
  Вопрос:Что анализировать в коде, что бы менять значение VYDOX_OUTPUT_FONT в  зависимости от применяемой разметки(устройства).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер экрана:

```
DisplayMetrics myDisplayMatrics= new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(myDisplayMetrics);
```

и дальше: `myDisplayMetrics.heightPixels` и `myDisplayMetrics.widthPixels`

плотность пикселов:

```
int myDensity = getResources().gerDisplayMetrics().density;
switch (myDensity) {
  case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    ...
}
```